# Visual Studio vs GCC, concerning "'__cdecl' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]"

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

I need to suppress a GCC (or what I believe is GCC) compiler warning in Visual Studio. Usually these Visual Studio compiler warnings come with a warning code, but this one is just null.

The warning is `'__cdecl' attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]`. I believe I need to suppress all `-Wattributes` warnings for my .h file, but I am not sure how to do that.

The block that is giving me the troubles is inside *LoggerHelper.h*:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    using LoggerFuncPtr = void(__cdecl *)(wchar_t*);
#else
    using LoggerFuncPtr = void(__attribute__((__cdecl)) *)(wchar_t*); 
#endif
```

Comment: I think that for GCC the name `cdecl` is used with out the leading underscores.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Do you know how I would go about suppressing it? Do I need to include some suppression line in the file itself, or is there an option inside of Visual Studio that I could switch/add to a list?

Comment: Read gcc's doc? On the command line, option -Wxxx enables warning xxx, -Wno-xxx disables it.

Comment: You don't need to change command line options or suppress warnings, you need to fix  the line of code like so:  `using LoggerFuncPtr = void(__attribute__((cdecl)) *)(wchar_t*);`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelBurr, that solved my issue.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Would you like to make an answer? It seems a decent question with a good answer, so there might be some upvotes for you. But actually, I mostly want this out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC's `cdecl` attribute doesn't have leading underscores, the declaration should look like:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    using LoggerFuncPtr = void(__cdecl *)(wchar_t*);
#else
    using LoggerFuncPtr = void(__attribute__((cdecl)) *)(wchar_t*); 
#endif
```